# edit user after press submit show error

Tags: php, edit

I having a problem with my edit user. after clicked the submit button it will show the error of "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"
this is the error code for it.
I have no idea what happened with my code. I do try debug it many times.

```
<?php
//set session start
session_start();

function renderForm($UID,$Username,$Unitno,$Cont,$PW,$UEmail,$UPay,$JD,$PD)
    {?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><link href="styles/style1.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" title="CSS" type="text/css" /></head><body><!-- Begin Container -->
    <div id="container">
        <!-- Begin Masthead -->
        <div id="masthead">

        </div>
        <!-- End Masthead -->

        <!-- Begin Navigation -->
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="homepage.php">Home Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="notice.php">Notice</a></li>
                <li><a href="feedback.php">Feedback</a></li>
                <li><a href="user.php">User</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- End Navigation -->

        <!-- Begin Content -->
        <div id="content">
            <!-- #BeginEditable "content" -->
            <h1>Edit User</h1>

            <hr/>

            You are on: 
                <a href="user.php">User</a>

            <br/>

            <form action="" method="post">
                <table align="center">
                <tr>
                <p align = "center"><strong>User ID: </strong> <?php echo $UID?></p><br/>
                    <td align = "right">

                    <strong>User Name: </strong> <input type="text" name="UserName" value = "<?php echo $Username; ?>" /><br/>
                    <strong>Unit No: </strong> <input type="text" name="UnitNo" value = "<?php echo $Unitno; ?>" /><br/>
                    <strong>Contact: </strong> <input type="text" name="Contact" value = "<?php echo $Cont; ?>" /><br/>
                    <strong>Password: </strong> <input type="text" name="Password" value = "<?php echo $PW; ?>" /><br/>
                    <strong>Email: </strong> <input type="text" name="UserEmail" value = "<?php echo $UEmail; ?>" /><br/>
                    <strong>User Pay: </strong> <input type="text" name="UPayment" value = "<?php echo $UPay; ?>" /><br/>
                    <strong>Join Date: </strong> <input type="text" name="JoinDate" value = "<?php echo $JD; ?>" /><br/>
                    <strong>Pay Date: </strong> <input type="text" name="PayDate" value = "<?php echo $PD; ?>" /><br/>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

                    </td>
                    </tr></table>
            <br/>

            <hr/>
        </div>
        <!-- End Content -->

        <!-- Begin Footer -->
        <div id="footer">
            <p>
                Copyright &copy; 2012 Condominium Management. All Rights Reserved.
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- End Footer -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Container -->
</body>
</html><?php


include ("connection_db.php");



                        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                        {

                        if (is_numeric($_POST['UID']))
                        {
                            $UserID = $_POST['UserID'];
                            $UserName= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['UserName']));
                            $UnitNo = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['UnitNo']));
                            $Contact = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Contact']));
                            $Password= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Password']));
                            $UEmail = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['UserEmail']));
                            $UPayment = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['UPayment']));
                            $JoinDate= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['JoinDate']));
                            $PayDate = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['PayDate']));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $sql = "UPDATE User SET UserName='$UserName', UnitNo='$UnitNo', Contact='$Contact', Password='$Password', UserEmail='$UEmail', UPayment='$UPayment', JoinDate='$JoinDate', PayDate='$PayDate' where UserID = $UserID";

                            mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                            header("Location:user.php");
                        }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        if(isset($_GET['UserID']) && is_numeric($_GET['UserID']) && $_GET['UserID']>0)
                        {
                        $uid = $_GET['UserID'];
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM User Where UserID = $uid") or die (mysql_error());
                        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                        if($row)
                        {
                        $UID = $row['UserID'];
                        $Username = $row['UserName'];
                        $Unitno = $row['UnitNo'];
                        $Cont = $row['Contact'];
                        $PW = $row['Password'];
                        $UEmail = $row['UserEmail'];
                        $UPay = $row['UPayment'];
                        $JD = $row['JoinDate'];
                        $PD = $row['PayDate'];

                        renderForm($UID, $Username, $Unitno, $Cont, $PW, $UEmail, $UPay, $JD, $PD, '');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        echo "No result";
                        }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        echo 'Error';
                        }
                        }?>
```

Comment: You should echo out the string you're passing into the mysql_query line.

Comment: You need to indent your code. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes I don't know why I bother.  I looked through your long-ass code and figured out the error just by inspection and you don't even give me an accept.  Is it so much to ask that when you ask for help and then get it, you bother to say thanks?

Answer (score 1):

You should indeed print out the sql statement:

`$sql = "UPDATE User SET UserName='$UserName', UnitNo='$UnitNo', Contact='$Contact', Password='$Password', UserEmail='$UEmail', UPayment='$UPayment', JoinDate='$JoinDate', PayDate='$PayDate' where UserID = $UserID";`

```
echo "MY QUERY: ".$sql;
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
header("Location:user.php");
```

Please post your result and i guess we can easily detect the error.

**Update**: make sure `$UserID` is defined (not empty) and add a semicolon:

`$sql = "UPDATE User SET UserName='$UserName', UnitNo='$UnitNo', Contact='$Contact', Password='$Password', UserEmail='$UEmail', UPayment='$UPayment', JoinDate='$JoinDate', PayDate='$PayDate' where UserID = '$UserID' ;";`

Comment: MY QUERY: UPDATE User SET UserName='', UnitNo='', Contact='', Password='', UserEmail='', UPayment='', JoinDate='', PayDate='' where UserID = You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

this is the message

Comment: there is no UserID! followed by a semiciolon (';')

Answer (score 1):

I see two mistakes.

1. You make a reference to `$_POST['UserID']`, but you don't have a field named UserID, only UID.
2. You use a variable called `$UserID` in your UPDATE statement, but this variable is only ever set by other code paths, so when the UPDATE runs it has not been initialized and, as such, is probably an empty string.

I think it's the second one which is causing your problem.  Your UPDATE statement is probably ending with `where UserID =`.  But, as others have said, the only way to tell for sure, is to print out your query and see what's wrong with it.

In general, to debug your SQL problems, you should:

1. Modify your code to print out all of your SQL queries.
2. Examine the queries to see if you can tell which one is having the problems and where the mistake is
3. If not, try running them by hand to see which work and which don't
4. Once you've found the bug in the query string, see what went wrong with creating it to cause that bug.
5. Fix it

Answer (score 0):

Replace `where UserID = $UserID"` with `where UserID = '$UserID';"` Don't forget those quotes and semi-colon